# java action listener on menu, and not on menu item

Tags: java, swing, menu, onclick, actionlistener

I need enlightenment.

how to add action actionListener event bind to the menu, and not bind to the menu ITEM 
here is the demo code, that works(on menuITEM)..

```
menuFileItem.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    System.out.println("It works");
                }
            }
        );
```

but when i try the same , but just on the MENU itself it doesn't work!

```
menuFile.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Plz work... :( ");
                }
            }
        );
```

is it possible to add listener to menu? i taught listener could be added to everything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add an `ActionListener` to a `JMenu` as this method is inherited from `AbstractButton`. [(JMenu Documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html)

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("MyMenu");
menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){...});
```

But, it is not intended to be used this way: [JMenu ignores ActionEvent](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4108937). You should use `MenuEvent` and `MenuListener` instead.

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("MyMenu");
menu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("menuSelected");
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("menuDeselected");
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("menuCanceled");
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: i did that, i declaired menu, before constructor, and i created it in constructor of that class, and when i try to implement menu.addActionListener ..... it doesn't work. 

can you provide, working example of your solution to this.

Comment: WORKS! thank you!! i just got smarter for 1 method... :D joke... thank you really, now my app will look smoother.. i started to work in java few days ago, from scratch .. so i'm in learning phase right now. THANKS AGAIN MATE! God Bless you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I use this `addMouseListener()`, because when you click over a `JMenu`, it marks it blue and executes the event just after.

I think it's that effect that you want.

Here it works using this code:
I declare:

```
JMenu jmCadastrar = new JMenu("Cadastrar");

jmCadastrar.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution also works with multiple JMenus.

Answer (score 1):

If you instantiated JMenu class to bulid a menu object, try the method addMenuListener().

Comment: this sounds interesting, can you provide working example? i never used that method.

Comment: Of course.Following is the code you can complete it.  JMenu menuFileItem= new JMenu();
      menuFileItem.addMenuListener(
          new MenuListener(){
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                }
            public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
               }
            public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
} } );

Answer (score 1):

based on the previous answers, I added an additional **key listener** to the solution.

Here is a convenience function:

```
public static void bind(JMenu menu, ActionListener listener) {

        menu.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                listener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(e.getSource(), ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Delegate"));
            }
        });

        menu.addMenuKeyListener(new MenuKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void menuKeyPressed(MenuKeyEvent e) {

                if(e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    return;
                }

                // Find out if the menu is the currently selected menu element
                MenuElement[] selectionPath = e.getMenuSelectionManager().getSelectedPath();

                // Because the JMenu will open a popup menu, the menu is the penultimate element in the path
                if (selectionPath.length < 2) {
                    return;
                }

                MenuElement selectedMenu = selectionPath[selectionPath.length - 2];

                if (selectedMenu == menu) {
                    listener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(e.getSource(), ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Delegate"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void menuKeyTyped(MenuKeyEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void menuKeyReleased(MenuKeyEvent e) {}
        });
    }
```