# On demand population of dropdown menu Java/Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

When I code a popup menu, I can check the mouse event and then
before calling show() prepare the menu.

Now I want a similar functionality for drop down menus, that
live in the menu bar. For example I have the following menu
bar layout:

```
Menu 1
   MenuItem 1.1
      MenuItem 1.1.1
      MenuItem 1.1.2
      ..
      MenuItem 1.1.n
Menu 2
```

Basically I want to generate the list MenuItem 1.1.1, MenuItem 1.1.2,
..., MenuItem 1.1.n dynamically when the drop down menu is invoked and
before it is shown.

How could I do this in Java/Swing? Is there a call back that covers both
L&F specific keyboard/mouse invokations of the menu bar?

Best Regards

Comment: PopupMenuListener is only available for JPopupMenu and JComboBox. I don't find it in JMenuBar.

Comment: You're looking for a MenuListener: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#addMenuListener%28javax.swing.event.MenuListener%29

Comment: I think this question has been already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358710/java-action-listener-on-menu-and-not-on-menu-item).

Comment: darn ... my bad, didn't read carefully enough ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `javax.swing.JMenuBar` instead of a `java.​awt.MenuBar`.
These MenuBars can add `javax.​swing.JMenu`s which have a `addMenuListener(MenuListener l)` method.

In this MenuListener you can dynamically add and delete the menus.

```
@Override
public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
    // Put your logic here
    JMenu dynamicMenu = (JMenu) e.getSource();
    dynamicMenu.add(new JMenuItem("MenuItem 1.1.1"));
}

@Override
public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
    // Remove all MenuItems
    JMenu dynamicMenu = (JMenu) e.getSource();
    dynamicMenu.removeAll();
}

@Override
public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
    // Remove all MenuItems
    JMenu dynamicMenu = (JMenu) e.getSource();
    dynamicMenu.removeAll();
}
```

To add the JMenuBar to a JFrame use the `setJMenuBar(JMenuBar menubar)` method.

Comment: I guess via the show() in JPopupMenu I can assure that population is done before hand. Not sure how menuSelected() will work, whether I will get unnecessary double populations, when moving around in the menu bar with the mouse. But I guess will be able to fix with some additional state.

Comment: @Cookie Monster not valid for JMenu is there only setVisible (show is depreciated ??? or too layz look into API), btw this idea is wrong, JMenuItems should be prepared and added to JMenu before any MouseEvent, prerequisities will be the same, just bussines view

Comment: @CookieMonster curious: why/how exactly is _unnecessary double population_ problematic? And why is it so extremely dynamic to start with? From a usability perspective, menus shouldn't change too much ...

Comment: @Cookie Monster `depends on the current text caret position` and selection and highlighter, are you sure that we talking about JMenuBar, JMenu and with JMenuItems, isn't better to use JPopup & JMenuItems, especially if viewToModel returns all that you need (sure coud be valid for JMenu with JMenuItems too)

Comment: @Cookie Monster did you tried to setEnable(false) for unwanted JMenuItem(s) in JMenu

Comment: @Cookie Monster use some of variations that came from `MenuListener`, call `JMenu.setVisible(false)` change contens than call `JMenu.setVisible(true)`, notice never tried, just to simulating similair steps as you used before `JPopup.show(.........)`

Comment: @Cookie Monster clear bump so different workaround to your original question, hehehheheeeeee I love g*u*e*a*r*i*l*l*a coders, please to try edit tags in your question, no issue to create popup window contains JList with autocomplete funcionality, attach to the mouselistener and or with viewToModel & caret & selection, have to use Document :-)