# JMenuItem set alignment & maximumsize

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a help button on a JMenuBar. Currently I can make it align to right using this

```
helpItem.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

The issue is that it takes up the entire space of the JMenuBar so you can basically press anywhere on the empty space of the JMenuBar and it will press that button. I fixed that by overriding the size of the JMenuItem using this

```
    JMenuItem helpItem = new JMenuItem() {
        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            Dimension d1 = super.getPreferredSize();
            Dimension d2 = super.getMaximumSize();
            d2.width = d1.width;
            return d2;
        }
    };
```

However, after I override getMaximumSize, setComponentOrientation doesn't align the JMenuItem to the right.

EDIT (Current code):

```
private void createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar newMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        newMenuBar.setName("");
        JMenu newMenu = new JMenu("Menu");
        JMenuItem updateItem = new JMenuItem("Update");
        JMenuItem aboutMe = new JMenuItem("About");
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenuItem helpItem = new JMenuItem();
        URL iconPath = getClass().getResource("/help.png");
        helpItem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(iconPath));
        addMenuItemActionListeners(updateItem, aboutMe, exitItem, helpItem);
        newMenu.add(updateItem);
        newMenu.add(aboutMe);
        newMenu.add(exitItem);
        newMenuBar.add(newMenu);
        newMenuBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        newMenuBar.add(helpItem);
        this.setJMenuBar(newMenuBar);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to manually set the component size, avoid it because it's a bad practice and could break your layout.

If you just want to align the help menu on the right, you can make use of `Box.createHorizontalGlue` method.

Yuo can add all the other menus you're gonna use (of course, if you need), then add the glue, and then add all the other menus you want to have aligned to the right side.

This is an example:

[image]

And this is a MCVE to achieve the above result:

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class GlueMenuBarTest
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar (createGlueMenuBar ());
        frame.setSize (500, 250); // just for convenience, use pack () in a real app.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
    private static JMenuBar createGlueMenuBar () {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar ();
        menuBar.add (new JMenu ("File"));
        menuBar.add (new JMenu ("Edit"));
        menuBar.add (new JMenu ("Search"));
        menuBar.add (Box.createHorizontalGlue ());
        menuBar.add (new JMenu ("Help"));
        return menuBar;
    }
}
```

If you comment the lines where i add other menus on the left, it will work as well.

Comment: Just tried adding the glue before adding my item and it looks like this now http://prntscr.com/hgrm7u

Comment: @Cows42 Have you tried my code? You should be able to understand why your code isn't doing what you expect. Are you still using setComponentOrientation ()? You don't need it anymore! Are you still changing the size manually? You don't have to do it! Are you setting a different layout for your menubar? You should not ... Post a [mcve] if you need help to fix your code, but i posted you a working example ...

Comment: @Cows42 Just replace `JMenuItem helpItem = new JMenuItem();` with `JMenu helpItem = new JMenu();`. Don't add `JMenuItems` directly to `JMenuBar`, use always a `JMenu`.

Comment: @Cows42 If you want to directly perform some action when you click a JMenu, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9358860/6449672) which will show you how to use a MenuListener.

Comment: @Cows42 I'm glad it helped :)